# Mypy running extremely slow, are there any known possible causes?

Tags: python, mypy

When I say extremely slow I really mean it. It takes about half a minute for it the print the error in the following very simple code:

```
def aaa(a: int, b: int, c: int) -> int:
    return 1

print(aaa(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

For real code it takes forever, after several minutes waiting I gave up on waiting for it to end. I tried doing a `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall mypy` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: How exactly do you run mypy? Just `mypy mcve.py` works fine for me in ~2s.

Comment: @Robert I use vscode, noticed the problem when I ran into a bug mypy should've detected before compiling. However I tried running `mypy aaa.py` directly on the terminal (aaa.py being the file with the simple code in the question) and the issue persists

Comment: Maybe try deleting `.mypy_cache`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga deleted it, that didn't change anything either

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: @Janilson Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @drewag it magically fixed itself at some point... My best guess of what might've happened is that restarting the computer might have fixed it. I usually just close the lid of my laptop instead of turning it off, so eventually when windows update forced me to restart perhaps that was what did it. But that's just a guess

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly it's so slow, but running it like `mypy --cache-fine-grained <args...>` is the only thing that helped. Using the daemon as suggested by mypy didn't speed it up, but caching sped up subsequent runs. The first one still takes many seconds.

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/additional_features.html#remote-cache